# Change the position of additional attribute selector in hybris backoffice advanced search

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

[image]

I want to move this Additional Attribute selector Dropdown to the top else I need to disable the type ahead in last row initially and when i click on + button, I need to enable the typing in editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the additional attribute selector to the top then try to delete the above two fields (ID and Name) by clicking the cross button ( ❌) in right side.
Then select the field name you want to search with from the drop-down and add it by clicking the + button at right side. And adjust you required fields accordingly.